# how to implement low latency ConcurrentQueue?

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, concurrency, queue

i have benchmarked 2 versions of concurrent queue, one is concurrency::concurrent_queue< uint64_t > from MSVC2015, another is handwritten version

handwrittend version is quite simple, it utilises std::mutex+std::queue

void push(T&& val) operation is straightforward: {_m.lock(); _q.push(val); _m.unlock();}

bool try_pop(T& val) is as floolwing: {lock(); if( _queue.empty() ) {_m.unlock(); return false; } else { T=_q.pop(); _m.unlock(); return true; }

that it blocks mutex, checks if queue is empty, then unblocks and returns false if it is, or assigns T& val value, unblocks and returns true;

benchmark is multiple writer (for instance: 16 threads on 4core 3770K) and single highest priority reader; exposing behavoid of multiple clients-single serever; bench has fixed number of iterations (16M), so each thread-writer just stores current timestamp (QueryPerformanceCounter() call) for 1M times;

and the reader aggregates time deltas(it calls QueryPerformanceCounter() upon try_pop() returns true; and calculated time difference) and, on completion, it calculates average latency (all timeDeltas' sum divided by number of iteration)
so, i explained everything, just allow me to not paste whole code here; it is simple, me is quite lazy to seek for code(was few days ago, on another PC) and must use pastebin/whatsoever.. better, i love to print now and you can now understand and answer, if you know it :)

and i met quite an strange behaviour:
my implementation exposes FAST overall processing(around 2s), but a latency of 800ms on average (think 1s, dependent of process/thread priority, background processes, presence of debugger, so on)
and MS concurrency::concurrent_queue implementation exposes ultra-low avg latency,  (<10ms, usually 1-2ms), but extremely high run-time (cant exactly remember, about 30-40s, i remembered around 20-30 times slower than my impl)

so here is the question - do there two approaches exists? one for lowest latency and another for lowest run time? or what could you say?
What is low-latency approach? (i mean agorithmically, C/pseudocode samples are highly appreciated)
how councurrecny::coucurrent_queue::push() and try_pop() are written?

Comment: its kinda situation with message handler server, where messages could arrvie from multiple threads/ and  must be handled ASAP: there is a single highest priority message server (like  an idea in a microKernel OS, but in windows usermode)

Comment: i've heard of multiple readers-single writer lock, is it possible to have some fast multiple-writer, but single exclusive-lowest-latency reader?

Comment: google for c++ disruptor

Comment: Can you please show us the benchmarking code. I suspect the code is just broken and is using up the timeslice. (What does it do if `try_pop` returns `false`?)

Comment: okay, take a look.. i tried different things. https://pastebin.com/h2Ldp8iN